# PyQt6 custom signals and slots connection

Tags: python, pyqt6

I have a button as a separate class and main window class. On main window there are 2 QlineEdit widgets. I want to take text from them and process it somehow when button clicked. The processing should happen in button class, besause i want to try slots and signals connections. ButtonWidget class accepts text from QLineEdits and returns it somehow. Returned text then shows in QLabel. For now text dont changes, though text emits to the processing slot-function. Then it should emit back, but it is not working.

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit, QWidget
from PyQt6.QtCore import pyqtSignal as Signal, pyqtSlot as Slot


class ButtonWidget(QPushButton):
    accepted_text = Signal(str, str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setText("Accept Text")

    @Slot(str, str)
    def accept_text(self, text1, text2):
        text1 = text1.upper()
        text2 = text2.title()
        self.accepted_text.emit(text1, text2)


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    pushed_text = Signal(str, str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.line1 = QLineEdit(placeholderText="enter text")
        self.line2 = QLineEdit(placeholderText="enter text")

        self.button_widget = ButtonWidget()

        self.label = QLabel("")

        layout.addWidget(self.line1)
        layout.addWidget(self.line2)
        layout.addWidget(self.button_widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.pushed_text.connect(self.button_widget.accept_text)
        self.button_widget.clicked.connect(self.change_label)

        self.show()

    def change_label(self):
        text1 = self.line1.text()
        text2 = self.line2.text()
        self.pushed_text.emit(text1, text2)
        self.label.setText(text1 + " " + text2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I tried to connect function `accept_text()` from ButtonWidget class with `pushed_text` signal from QLineEdit from main Window class. `accept_text()` function should return processed text somehow.

[image: resulting window]

it should be STACK Overflow instead of stack overflow. Is there any way to properly connect slots and signals between classes?

Comment: Making your own signals and slots can get a little confusing. For an application like this, usually one would use a regular QPushButton and connect the clicked signal to a user-defined function. It's also worth mentioning that one of the nice features of QLineEdit is that they emit a returnPressed signal which fires when user presses Return/Enter key so you can run some code then. Finally, if you ever get into more complex GUIs, you'll want to use UI files and helper functions will automagically connect signals to functions named on_<widgetname>_<signal>() in your MainWindow.

Comment: For learning basic PyQt6/Pyside6, I really like [ZetCode tutorials](https://zetcode.com/pyqt6/). For learning how to use UI files from Qt Designer, [this tutorial](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/tutorials/basictutorial/uifiles.html) is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

I guess i kinda figured it out, but it is kinda messy. Maybe there is a better way. All this is very confusing, if you know better way, please let me know. What i changed:

```
class ButtonWidget(QPushButton):
    accepted_text = Signal(str, str)
    returned_text = Signal(str, str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setText("Accept Text")

        self.accepted_text.connect(self.accept_text)

    @Slot(str, str)
    def accept_text(self, text1, text2):
        text1 = text1.upper()
        text2 = text2.title()
        self.returned_text.emit(text1, text2)
```

I added new signal **returned_text** to the ButtonWidget. I connected **accepted_text** signal with the **accept_text** slot-function. This function now emit **returned_text** signal.

In MainWindow window i deleted **pushed_text** signal and added the following code:

```
    self.button_widget.returned_text.connect(self.update_label)
    self.button_widget.clicked.connect(self.change_label)

    self.show()

def update_label(self, text1, text2):
    self.label.setText(text1 + " " + text2)

def change_label(self):
    text1 = self.line1.text()
    text2 = self.line2.text()
    self.button_widget.accepted_text.emit(text1, text2)
```

I connected **returned_text** signal with the **update_label** function. Button clicked event still connected with **change_label** function. Inside that function we get elements we want to change and emit **accepted_text** that is connected with **accept_text** slot-function inside ButtonWidget.

Now it works as i wanted it to work.

[image: Result]

Here is the full code:

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit, QWidget
from PyQt6.QtCore import pyqtSignal as Signal, pyqtSlot as Slot


class ButtonWidget(QPushButton):
    accepted_text = Signal(str, str)
    returned_text = Signal(str, str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setText("Accept Text")

        self.accepted_text.connect(self.accept_text)

    @Slot(str, str)
    def accept_text(self, text1, text2):
        text1 = text1.upper()
        text2 = text2.title()
        self.returned_text.emit(text1, text2)


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.line1 = QLineEdit(placeholderText="enter text")
        self.line2 = QLineEdit(placeholderText="enter text")

        self.button_widget = ButtonWidget()

        self.label = QLabel("")

        layout.addWidget(self.line1)
        layout.addWidget(self.line2)
        layout.addWidget(self.button_widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.button_widget.returned_text.connect(self.update_label)
        self.button_widget.clicked.connect(self.change_label)

        self.show()

   def update_label(self, text1, text2):
        self.label.setText(text1 + " " + text2)

   def change_label(self):
        text1 = self.line1.text()
        text2 = self.line2.text()
        self.button_widget.accepted_text.emit(text1, text2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: What is the point of the button subclass and the convoluted use of custom signals? All you need to do is connect a slot to the button's `clicked` signal and update the label within that slot (i.e. `def change_label(self): self.label.setText( f'{self.line1.text().upper()} {self.line2.text().title()}')`).

Comment: i wanted to practice in breaking code into small pieces, so it be easier to develop bigger projects

Comment: @Lethnis Other than what ekhumoro wrote, even assuming you actually needed such a convoluted approach for some **valid** reason, it doesn't make any sense to create two separated signals. Just connect the button's `accepted_text` signal to a function that accepts that signature (such as `update_label` in the code above). The `accepted_text` signal is completely useless, as you're emitting that signal externally to call an internal function, which doesn't make sense: just call that function directly.

Comment: @Lethnis I understand that you want to experiment and understand things, but you should also try to do that with *practical* purposes: a slot/function is normally connected to a signal because that signal is supposed to possibly *act* on something (change the state of some object), but you're not doing any of that: what `accept_text` fundamentally does is to take an input and return a value based on that input, and signals are not intended for that. You should connect `clicked` to a slot that eventually calls another function and finally uses its return values to set the text.